# VB script to automatically opt-in for office 2013 on windows 8

Tags: vbscript, ms-office, office-2013

Does anybody know how to skip the opt-in popup during office 2013 first run. On office 2010, the following vbs can be used to skip the dialog:

```
Set ServiceManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager")
ServiceManager.ClientApplicationID = "My App"
Set NewUpdateService = ServiceManager.AddService2("7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d",7,"")
```

But it doesn't work with Office 2013 on Windows 8. Any idea how to modify the script?

Answer (score 2):

What about use office customization tool do disable opt-in?
features> modify user settings > microsoft office 2013 > Disable Opt-in Wizard on first run